# Theano missing packages

Tags: python, theano

I recently installed Theano on my macbook pro, and tried running an example code. I get the following error

ImportError: No module named theano.tensor

I upgraded Theano to it's latest version, using

sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps theano

and I get a message saying everything is up-to-date:

Requirement already up-to-date: theano in /anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Any idea how to proceed and what is causing the issue?

Comment: did you install via `pip` or `conda`?

Comment: Have you created your own script called `theano.py`? Can you do `import theano` in the Python console?